# Cronjob update permission

Tags: cron

I want to create a cronjob to update and upgrade a pi once every day. My only issue is that at some points it asks permission to use or free up disk space. Is there an option to a command to continue with the coronjob?

What I am trying to run:

```
30 2 * * * sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can use the root `crontab`. You can access it here:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then add your program:

```
30 2 * * * apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

And it will be run with root permissions.